# How would the world view superhumans that are more human or weaker?

Tags: science-fiction, super-powers, balancing-magic-systems, supernatural

When I say being more human. I'm not talking about a character being more relatable to an audience. Like Superman working in a 9 to 5 job. I'm more so talking about a superhuman character being more human when it comes to physicality.

Like an inverse version of Batman or something. For example, Batman is portrayed as just a normal guy who has no powers. But his willpower and his feats are impressive that you or his world would think he is superhuman. But he's actually not superhuman.

It's pretty much the opposite of this When it comes to Superhuman characters. Where a superhuman can be so weak that bullets can even kill him. And it's easy for normal humans to harm him. Even though he is a superhuman. How would society view powers that are really useless, mundane, or low tier?

With my original question, someone mentioned characters like Daredevil. Would a guy like Daredevil be able to get off with self-defense? If he ends up killing a dangerous normal human attacker. Or does his superpowers make it too hard for a judge to believe his life can be in danger? What if more than one attacker with weapons tries to kill Daredevil. What does the judge do here?

I can even bring up sports here too. Would weak/more human superhumans be eligible enough to compete in sports. Because their powers are so low tier they can blend in. Or does being superhuman still give them too much unfair advantages.

What happens when less strong people get superpowers. What if a small woman or small kid had Daredevil powers. How would self defense laws imply to them?

TLDR: How would a world/should react to low level superhumans?

Comment: [Mystery Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Men) - great movie, with the caveat that the box office is cruel to sf/fantasy movies I like.

Comment: This seems to be a question about writing a story and how the story resonates with an audience rather than a question about building a fictional world.

Comment: How do you mean he's superhuman then? Perhaps a powerful psychic (Professor X), a blind martial-artist/acrobat (Daredevil). This seems like a [writing.se] question, sure you can write them to have whatever character strengths/flaws you like. Could you clarify where the worldbuilding problem to be solved is?

Comment: There are so many worldbuilding aspects to this question. I don't even know where to start. First of all. It has something to do with the way society views superhumans. What would a world consider superhuman or not super? Even self-dense laws can be brought up here. Can this superhuman win a self-defense case, because of his powers being weak? Or self-defense laws should not apply to superhumans because they have superpowers. Because superhuman hitting normal humans back. Is like men hitting women's back. There are so many Worldbduilding questions here with the vulnerability of superhumans.

Comment: Might I suggest that you pick *one*. We're best at answering focused questions, one at a time. You can [edit] when you've decided.

Comment: Please keep in mind that there are plenty of questions about worldbuilding that are explicitly off topic on this site. Brainstorming, discussion, or questions asking for people's opinions are not a good fit and likely to be closed.

Comment: @EdockEdock My advice when you don't know anything or you're not sure where to go is to take one of the path and see where it goes. You can and you're always free to go back if you realize it's not a really good one. For instance... My normal superhumans are competing in martial fights in the USA, I'll say that people don't accept it. Now what happens about these people and the fights?  And in the case of creative activities what do I feel and think about it as I unravel the wool ball? If still unsure continue to assume new elements ^^.

Comment: "More human" - meaning that superhero may have a number of superpowers, but [Enhanced Durability](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Peak_Human_Durability/Enhanced) is not one of them?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question.

Comment: how do we see people who hold a lot of power today? people with far above average intelligence, or record holders in lifting weights, or even billionaires like Musk, Bezos or Gates? They have some fans, but overall they are not very respected for their powers. X Men also offers a lot of that script of people with special powers being discriminated against.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real rules for this based on the real world, as all our social conventions would fall apart if there were people capable of the standard comic book powers.

Everything about the world would be different.

Laws would have to be written to enable vigilantes to fight criminals in the street, whatever laws you come up with would decide the self defense cases, was daredevil a registered vigilante, was he on the clock at the time and pursuing a case?  Are you only allowed to fight crime when wearing your colourful spandex costume?

Sports would be similar, look at the controls for drug abuse in sports and the discussions about allowing trans athletes to compete.
Would Captain america be banned from competing for Drug abuse, would superman be banned for having an unfair genetic makeup?  Is there a test they can do to detect if someone has powers?
Would anyone be interested in watching the un-powered Olympics when you can watch god-like beings that can run around the  planet in a blink of the eye or lift mountains.
There would probably be more super powered people interested in earning money in super contests then in risking their lives fighting super villains.

Would people be so scared of the potential for hidden super powers that they would test people and put them in concentration camps to protect the normal people?

Most comics don't really stray too much from the realm of super crime fighting because it breaks down too quickly.  Keep the scope of your story relatively small and only hint at the wider world